# Pycharm doesn't recognise data type after chaining function calls

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm

I have a pandas DataFrame `data_one`, some rows of which contain string values. I wanted to exclude them and drop the NaNs. So I did

```
data_one = date_one.convert_objects(convert_numeric=True).dropna()
```

then Pycharm failed to recognise data_one as DataFrame so autocompletion failed.

When I do this on REPL, i.e. `type(data_one)`, I can see it is a DataFrame.

Anyone had some problem?

Comment: ok I guess it is still because Python is dynamically typed.

Comment: Try to add some type hint. Useful for pycharm to auto-complete and type check sometimes.

Comment: Thanks how would you do it to add type hint for the above line? It's in the middle of a function and not one of the arguments.

Comment: Write it for `data_one` var and `convert_objects()`, `dropna()` method before this.